# Does anyone know how to create a folder tree in the Eclipse DDMS File Explorer?

Tags: android, emulation, explorer, ddms

I'm trying to create the path "/package name/databases" under the sdcard folder. Anybody got the secret?

Comment: why to store an application's database file (*.db) outside to it's original path (data/data/APPLICATION_PACKAGE/databases/DATABASE_NAME.db) ?

Comment: @Vegolath - several possible reasons.  It could be big.  Also, if it's in the app's private storage area, DDMS can't access it (except on the emulator or a rooted device)

Comment: @Chris Stratton, try avoiding shipping heavy databases with you application. If it is possible try remote your db on a server then access it with your app, like REST app.

Comment: It's not my question or application.  Content on the SDCARD is hopefully not shipped "with" an application, but there are many legitimate reasons for installing large datasets there - such as usability when the mobile network is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `fileobj.mkdir()` method from `File` class? Check if the directory already exist if not exist then create it.[Refer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

And don't forget about writing permissions for external storage, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the permissions. It's not relevant for this but it will be in a subsequent activity. [See comment above ...]

Answer (score 1):

Just select the parent folder and click the small **+** ("New Folder"). Do this again for the next subfolder.

[image]

Comment: Please note: I'm trying to do this in the emulator, not an actual phone! My sdcard folder is under mnt. It doesn't appear to allow any additions ...

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Have you actually added a sdcard to your emulator? By default the card-size field is empty, resulting in no sdcard (There should be a notification in the statusbar in this case). The file explorer shows an sdcard folder in this case though, but i get a read-only message if I try to create something in there. But if I have added some space for the card, it works for me in an 1.6 AVD and in a 2.3.3 one.

Comment: I don't recall adding anything to this tree previously. I'm running under 2.2 API8. When I check the settings in the AVD, the size of the sdcard storage is 31.49mb!

Comment: Mhm I can't even specify 31.49mb, the settings only allow me round numbers. Maybe your AVD is somehow damaged? Did you try creating a new one from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Creating SD Card

```
 Access to your Android SDK Tools folder and use command “mksdcard” in order to create one.

 By default installation on Windows, the Tools folder should be here:

  C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools
 Using following syntax to create your desired SD Card

  mksdcard [memory size] [output file]

For example, I’d like to create a SD card with 200 MB in memory and put the files in 
 C:\Personel\AndroidNewbie\SDCard with file named “sdcard_dev.iso“, I do like this:

 mksdcard 256M C:\Personel\AndroidNewbie\SDCard\<span class="skimlinks-unlinked">sdcard_dev.iso</span>
```

Then

Using SD Card

```
You’ve done creating your desired SD Card, now you need it to be used by Android emulator. Open Eclipse, 
   access to your project.
   On menu Run -> Run Configurations, click on Android Configuration on the left tree menu, click on tab 
  Target on the right pane. You will see at the bottom: “Additional Emulator Commandline Options” and an 
  Input/Edit box below:
 Just type your input sdcard following syntax   
  -sdcard [sdcard location]

 For example, with the SD Card I’ve created above, I type:  

 -sdcard C:\Personel\AndroidNewbie\SDCard\<span class="skimlinks-unlinked">sdcard_dev.iso</span>
```