# want to create folder in sdcard on AVD

Tags: android

I want to create folder in sdcard.
i am using following command in android terminal

cd sdcard
mkdir music

mkdir failed for music, Permission denied.

Comment: Go to `eclipse - windows - avd manager - select avd and edit - hardware - new - SDCard Support`

Comment: yes i added SDCard Support. but same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try below code.It working fine.

```
you need to run emulator before run the below commands.
use the adb shell command from the android tools folder.
eg (this was on windows):
cd android-sdk-windows\tools
adb shell
cd /sdcard/
mkdir myfolder
```

[image]
 [image]

Comment: adb shell.. this also giving permission denied

Comment: I am using linux. And i am running commands in terminal emulator. All commands accept LS and CD are giving Permission denied.

Comment: already tried it out.
adb command not found.

also this link
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card-of.html

Comment: then you need to set path upto android-sdk-tool in linux then after you can access that command.

Comment: I have added one audio file by using DDMS perspective. But i want to see this file in Android emulator. How can i see?

Comment: You can see it Music application in android emulator.

Comment: Please go into Gallery application/

Comment: yes now i am getting files in gallery. I have just restarted emulator.

Comment: nice. thanks much. very importantly, the emulator must be running at the time

Answer (score 2):

Try below links for creating folder in sdcard

Create folder terminal window below link :

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card-of.html

Create folder in programmatically :

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card.html

Thanks..!

Comment: go to android sdk folder under like below command                  D:>cd android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\                  after execute adb command..!

Comment: you want to create directory music...! music directory predefined directory try another name for directory...!

Comment: Inside \android-sdk-windows\platform-tools there is adb executable file. But on terminal adb command not found error is coming.

and i have tried different directory but same error.

Comment: In Linux terminal ADB command not found and
in terminal emulator Permission denied..

Comment: Ok try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222580/does-anyone-know-how-to-create-a-folder-tree-in-the-eclipse-ddms-file-explorer

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added SDCard support to your AVD.

Go to `eclipse - windows - avd manager - select avd and edit - hardware - new - SDCard Support`

And then Try the Command.

Answer (score 2):

While creating a directory, it is better to provide complete path instead of using `cd`

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the storage root directory.

Use the following command to create directory:

```
String filepath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music"
File fc=new File(filepath)
if(!fc.exists())       
        fc.mkdir();
```