# Not able to install emulator in linux machine from Android sdk

Tags: android, linux, centos, emulation

I am new to the Linux. I am using centos 7 and trying to install the emulator. I have installed android-sdk. while I try to create SD Card in the emulator I get error stating that : error while loading shared libraries: libgcc-s.so.1: cannot open shared object file. No such file or directory exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following links.

[want to create folder in sdcard on AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345127/want-to-create-folder-in-sdcard-on-avd)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/409905/apt-get-error-loading-libgcc-s-so-1

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/libgcc_s.so.1%3A+cannot+open+shared+object+file%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: I tried these but I get an error "apt-get : command not found"

Comment: And still I get this after trying the second link..."error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: try command "yum" instead of "apt-get" as you are using CentOS

Comment: "yum install libgcc_s.so.1" and                                                                                "yum install gcc-multilib"

Comment: It says that libgcc-4.8.3-9.el7.i686 is alredy installed and nothing to do...
But error still persist

Answer (score 0):

There isn't very much documentation for using the emulator with Centos.

I ran into a similar problem and found the issue was that I didn't set the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable.

Try executing this line before you start the emulator:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
```

Simply adding this line wasn't enough, I had to install the package because I didn't have it.

If you run into this issue, try:

```
yum provides \*/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Check to see which package you need (32-bit or 64-bit) and install it using this command:

```
 sudo yum install <package-name>
```

If the package is already installed, I suggest uninstalling all packages that refer to  the file and reinstalling only the one you need:

```
sudo yum remove <package-name>
```

Hopefully this is useful to someone... good luck!!